# How important is it to specify dispatchers/context in Kotlin coroutines? What happens if you don't specify them?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

If a coroutine was launched and no dispatcher was specified (eg. `GlobalScope.launch {}`), what dispatcher is used?

If that coroutine was launched in the main thread, would it use `Dispatchers.main`?

Also, what happens if you do not specify dispatchers or context in your coroutines? Say you did database operations, but didn't specify `Dispatchers.IO` anywhere. Would that cause any major issues?

Comment: `Would that cause any major issues?` pretty sure if you were doing db operations on the main thread you would know, because your app would crash, unless you've set your db to allow main thread operations, which you shouldn't

Comment: Yeah but if you ran the database operations in a coroutine (running on the main thread) without specifying `Dispatchers.IO` it would still work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If a coroutine was launched and no dispatcher was specified (eg. GlobalScope.launch {}), what dispatcher is used?

If no dispatcher is specified when calling the coroutine builder (`launch`, `async`, etc.), you get the dispatcher from whichever `CoroutineScope` you're starting your coroutine in. If there is no dispatcher in that scope's context, the coroutine will use `Dispatchers.Default` (see the doc of [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) for instance).

Note that the scope is the *receiver* of the coroutine builder call:

- if you see `GlobalScope.launch { ... }` then `GlobalScope` is the scope
- if you see `scope.launch { ... }`, look at that `scope`
- if you see `launch { .. }` without receiver, some instance of `CoroutineScope` must be available as `this` in that piece of code, and that's the scope (see below for an example on where it could be coming from)

Here is some info about the dispatchers used in the most common coroutine scopes:

If the scope is `GlobalScope`, then it doesn't have any dispatcher, so as mentioned before the coroutines will use `Dispatchers.Default`.

If the scope is `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` provided by Android, then coroutines will use `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` by default.

If the scope is created with the `CoroutineScope()` factory function without particular dispatcher, `Dispatchers.Default` will be used (see [the "Custom usage" section in the documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html)).

If the scope is created with the `CoroutineScope(someContext)` factory function, and `someContext` contains a dispatcher, then this dispatcher will be used to start coroutines.

If the scope is created using `MainScope()` and without particular dispatcher, it will use `Dispatchers.Main` as per [the same documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html).

If the scope is created with the `MainScope(someContext)` factory function, and `someContext` contains a dispatcher, then this dispatcher will be used to start coroutines.

If the scope is provided by `runBlocking` without specific dispatcher, then it will use a special dispatcher that works like an event loop and executes your coroutines in the thread that called `runBlocking` (which is nice because that thread would be blocked anyway).

If the scope is provided by `runBlocking(someContext) { ... }`, and `someContext` contains a dispatcher, then the child coroutines will use that dispatcher.

If the scope is provided by another (outer) coroutine builder like `launch` or `async` (which means your coroutine is a child of that coroutine), then the dispatcher will be taken from the scope that was used to launch the parent coroutine, unless they override it. So you can go all the way up until you reach one of the options mentioned above:

```kotlin
parentScope.launch {
    // here, this = child scope that gets the dispatcher from parentScope
    
    launch {
        // inherits from parent launch
    }
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // here, this = child scope with overridden dispatcher
        launch {
            // inherits Dispatchers.IO from parent launch's scope
        }
    }
}
```

> If that coroutine was launched in the main thread, would it use Dispatchers.main?

You probably can piece this together with the previous paragraph, but just to reiterate: it depends on the scope you're launching your coroutine in.

If you launch your coroutines from `lifecycleScope`/`viewModelScope`, then yes it will run on the main thread (in `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`).

If you call `runBlocking` from the main thread, then it would run coroutines on the main thread as well (but not in `Dispatchers.Main`), but you should definitely never do that in Android.

If you use something like `MainScope()` it would indeed run in `Dispatcher.Main`.

But in other cases, there is a high chance it runs on `Dispatchers.Default` - check the scope!

> Also, what happens if you do not specify dispatchers or context in your coroutines? Say you did database operations, but didn't specify `Dispatchers.IO` anywhere. Would that cause any major issues?

As you can see from the beginning of this answer, the dispatcher used depends on how you coroutine is launched. If we assume you don't specify any dispatcher anywhere, there is a good chance your coroutines are running on `Dispatchers.Main` (in Android) or `Dispatchers.Default`.

`Dispatchers.Main` would be really bad for IO stuff, because it would freeze your UI while the IO is happening. I believe Android probably crashes in case you run the wrong things in this dispatcher, but I haven't done Android dev in a while, so I can't say for sure.

`Dispatchers.Default` is a shared thread pool that's sized based on the number of cores of the machine executing the code, so it's suitable for CPU-bound tasks. If you launch a bunch of coroutines that perform blocking IO in this dispatcher, you could block all your threads and prevent other coroutines from running, which is really not ideal - it could cause lags or slowness, especially if you rely a lot on coroutines.

`Dispatchers.IO` is not magic, but it will spawn more threads as necessary if too many threads are blocked, so that other coroutines can run. You will still incur the additional memory of extra threads, but other coroutines will be free to run while some threads are blocked on IO.

You can read more about how to use dispatchers [in the documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/index.html).

Comment: **If you call runBlocking from the main thread, then it would run coroutines on the main thread as well (but not in Dispatchers.Main)** Please, elaborate this sentence. Does it mean that main thread is something different from Dispatchers.Main ?

Comment: @ibrahim Yes. The "main thread" refers to an actual JVM thread executing code. A dispatcher is a higher-level abstraction that implements mechanisms to dispatch tasks onto threads. `Dispatchers.Main` is one dispatcher implementation that makes use of the main thread to run tasks. `runBlocking` will by default (when not specifying a dispatcher) use its own event loop dispatcher that dispatches tasks onto the current thread, which can be the main thread. 2 different dispatchers using the same thread may behave differently. FYI, `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` also uses the main thread

Comment: Thank you. One more question that I have asked at below link                                                  (https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-invoking-join-method-on-a-coroutine-having-mainscope-as-scope-stopping-it/25464)                                                                                                       Please help me in understanding this scenario.

Comment: as the default dispatcher of **runBlocking** is **event loop**. Please, elaborate it what is it exactly? Also, in the following example when I specified _Dispatchers.Main_ for the **runBlocking**, it got locked. The body of **runBlocking** is not executing, why?                                                                                                                
`runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main){
        Log.d(TAG,Thread.currentThread().name) 
}

Comment: @ibrahim if you use `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main)` in the main thread, it means you're blocking the main thread (because you're using `runBlocking` on the main thread) but you also want the body of `runBlocking` to be dispatched onto the main thread using the `Main` dispatcher. Only `runBlocking`'s own event loop dispatcher can access the blocked thread, so you will have a deadlock if you try to use the main thread by other means (such as via `Dispatchers.Main`)